# How to add background color for ExpansionPanel in Flutter

Tags: flutter, expansion, flutter-layout

I am trying to style ExpansionPanel in Flutter but the color is not applying to the whole panel. I have tried both Container and Card widget, the color is not updating. Any Ideas?  I want to add background color to cover the entire ExpansionPanel. Is there a way to add the parent theme to the ExpansionPanel.

**Card**

```
Card(
  elevation: 2.0,
  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,right: 10.0,top: 10.0),
  child: ExpansionPanelList(
    expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
      setState(() {
        _items[index].isExpanded = !_items[index].isExpanded;
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
          setState(() {
            _reconfigureFAB();
          });
        });
      });
    },
    children: _items.map((IncludedItem item) {
      return ExpansionPanel(
        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
            child: Row(children: [
              Text(
                "What's included",
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Bold',
                    fontSize: 33.0,
                    color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor),
              ),
            ]),
          );
          ;
        },
        isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        body: Container(
          child: Text("body"),
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
```

**Container**

```
Container(
  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,right: 10.0,top: 10.0),
  child: ExpansionPanelList(
    expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
      setState(() {
        _items[index].isExpanded = !_items[index].isExpanded;
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
          setState(() {
            _reconfigureFAB();
          });
        });
      });
    },
    children: _items.map((IncludedItem item) {
      return ExpansionPanel(
        headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
            child: Row(children: [
              Text(
                "What's included",
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Bold',
                    fontSize: 33.0,
                    color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor),
              ),
            ]),
          );
          ;
        },
        isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        body: Container(
          child: Text("body"),
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`ExpansionPanelList` uses `cardColor` color from your theme.
You can specify it in `MaterialApp` (`theme` property) or override it in your widget:

```
Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
          child: Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(cardColor: Colors.red),
            child: ExpansionPanelList(
                ...
```

[image: expansionpanel]

Comment: Thank you !! I will remember this !!

Comment: Is there a way to change the dropdown icon color?

Comment: @ShashiKiran At the moment there is no way to change a color of `ExpandIcon`: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18992

Comment: @KirillShashov  How did you know the ExpansionPanelList uses cardColor color

Comment: @KirillShashov How to change the background color of only the header?

Comment: @NarayanChoudhary I haven't used Flutter for a long time, but it seems [impossible at the moment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/0b5d99eae6174b54ecca0a3fef6ba69228adc552/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_panel.dart#L505) to control the color of the entire header. 

They just execute `headerBuilder` and insert the result into the header.

Answer (score 5):

**ExpansionPanel** has a property called **backgroundColor**. You can add any color to this, and it will looks like this:
[image]

```
ExpansionPanel(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return const ListTile(
              title: Text("Quiz 0"),
            );
          },
          body: const ListTile(
            title: Text("body"),
          ),
          
        ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

anyone who is looking to change the expand_icon color -according to the update to expand_icon.dart 
If the panel is darker in color you can change the theme brightness to dark. This will change the icon color to white54. 
link - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/21328/commits/56bc3b066fbfc331619c72b82c0f657000076514

```
void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
home: new HomePage(),
theme: new ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    accentColor: Color(0xFF0277BD),
   textTheme: new TextTheme(
       body1:new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
   ),
    ))
```

image - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoLSL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the dropdown arrow color with `Brightness.dark` as recommended above but it did not work for me. Weirdly this did: `disabledColor: const Color(0xFF000000)`

Yolo, I'm keeping it in till the next app update